# passing multiple arguments to AsyncTask

Tags: android

Currently i am developing an application in which i am trying to do some work in background for which i am using AsyncTask.

i am creating the AsyncTask class like this

```
class callingweb extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{

public callingweb(Context context,Object objects,String...strings) {

}
}
```

and calling this class in my main class like this

```
callingweb cw=new callingweb(this,sampleDB,address,uname,pass);
cw.execute();
```

where  sampleDB is database object, address,uname and pass are string variables

now i want to pass one more view to the constructor i.e ListView lv

```
callingweb cw=new callingweb(login.this,sampleDB,lv,address,uname,pass);
```

please tell me how can i do this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add another constructor (constructor-overloading) in order to justify `ListView` as another parameter. For example:

```
//constructor without listview
public callingweb(Context context,Object objects,String...strings) {

}

//constructor with listview
public callingweb(Context context, ListView lv, Object objects,String...strings){

}
```

Comment: To expand on this. You would probably also have to store the passed reference to the `ListView` as a member variable. But there's really nothing special about it.

Comment: sorry for asking such a stupid question. i dont know how i forgot so simple thing. thanks a lot.